# How to enable GD library in php 7 in linux ubuntu?

Tags: php, ubuntu, installation, gd

I've try with

sudo apt-get install php7-gd

but the message is: E: Unable to locate package php7-gd

If someone could help me please...

Answer (score 14):

The package you are searching for is [php7.0-gd](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/php7.0-gd), so

`sudo apt-get install php7.0-gd`

should do the trick.

Comment: Don't forget to restart apache -  sudo service apache2 restart